# Custom field link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, function, hyperlink, customization

I have a custom field in the image attachments. 
I want to insert the custom link on my gallery. 
This is the custom field code that's works properly.

```
            function my_image_attachment_fields_to_edit($form_fields, $post) {  
                $form_fields["custom1"] = array(  
                    "label" => __("Image Links To"),  
                    "input" => "text",
                    "value" => get_post_meta($post->ID, "_custom1", true)  
                );        
                return $form_fields;  
            }  

            function my_image_attachment_fields_to_save($post, $attachment) {    
                if( isset($attachment['custom1']) ){  
                    update_post_meta($post['ID'], '_custom1', $attachment['custom1']);  
                }  
                return $post;  
            }  

            add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "my_image_attachment_fields_to_edit", null, 2); 
            add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "my_image_attachment_fields_to_save", null, 2); 




            function _save_attachment_url($post, $attachment) {
                if ( isset($attachment['url']) ) 
                    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_wp_attachment_url', esc_url_raw($attachment['url']) ); 
                return $post;
            }
            add_filter('attachment_fields_to_save', '_save_attachment_url', 10, 2);

            function _replace_attachment_url($form_fields, $post) {
                if ( isset($form_fields['url']['html']) ) {
                    $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_url', true );
                    if ( ! empty($url) )
                        $form_fields['url']['html'] = preg_replace( "/value='.*?'/", "value='$url'", $form_fields['url']['html'] );
                }
                return $form_fields;
            }
            add_filter('attachment_fields_to_edit', '_replace_attachment_url', 10, 2);
```

I want to put the link in a custom gallery on my function file. This is a part of my gallery code.

```
        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='card'>";
    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='card-block'>";
    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='container-portfolio'>";
    $output .= '<img class="" src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $id, 'medium', true) . '" />';

    I WANT TO INSERT THE CUSTOM LINK HERE

    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='overlay'>";
    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='card-body overlay-text'>";
```

Comment: Mario, please ask a specific question.   You already know how to fetch the custom field. You had get_post_meta($post->ID, "_custom1", true) .   Have you tried doing the same in your $output .=  ?

Comment: I tried this code, but dosn't work : $output .= '<a href="' .get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, '_custom1', true) . '" />';

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link only has 1 parameter.  It is not clear what it is you are trying to do.  I suggest read the codex. When debugging save and echo out or var_dump interim values so you can debug in steps. eg: $url = get_attachment_link($attachment->ID);  then var_dump($url); to check it has a value before using it.

Comment: Invalid HTML can also cause some thing not to appear as 'working' in the browser. View the source to see what actually got output.